# Calling static methods automagically in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, static, php-5.2, magic-methods

I've re-write the Idiorm ORM by Jamie Matthews to be completely compliant with PSR coding standards; however, I'd like to maintain backwards compatibility with the original code. The original used underscored method names, but PSR standards are camelCase. I've written a __call method to handle it when an object is created, but it doesn't work for the static methods. [This commit](https://github.com/kevinsperrine/idiorm/commit/ea382fe4b854b1c9d450d94d1c0af7ef21bcf6a0) shows the compatibility code.

Is there a way to make this work to call the static methods and still maintain php 5.2 compatibility?

Comment: I don't think so. __callStatic was only implemented in PHP 5.3 and I don't know of any possibility to do what you want before that.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think so either, but wanted to ask to make sure.

Comment: it's worth pointing out that PHP5.2 was declared end-of-life nearly two years ago now. If you're still using it, you're badly out of date, and likely have known security issues with your system, since no new patches have been released for 5.2 since then. Also, the PSR coding standards have been written specifically with PHP 5.3 and above in mind. I guess they don't expect anyone on 5.2 to be thinking about best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `__callStatic()`, which was just [introduced in PHP 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic); without that, I don't think you'll be able to implement this.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think so either, but wanted to ask to make sure.